# xml parser php attribute

Tags: php, android, xml

I am trying to create a PHP script to get values from string.xml android. Extracting XML file from the file and then parsing XML is one way.

This is string.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
    <string name="btn_search">Search</string>
    <string name="btn_around">Around</string>
    <string name="btn_load">Load more</string>
    <string name="btn_load_more">Load More</string>
    <string name="loading">Loading</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_pharmacy">Pharmacies</string>
    <string name="title_activity_around">AroundActivity</string>
    <string name="gps_network_enabled">GPS or Network is not enabled</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="fi">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>Almak</item>
        <item>Anlamak</item>
        <item>Anlasmak</item>
        <item>Anlatmak</item>
        <item>Ayrilmak</item>
    </string-array> </resources>
```

And this my simple script:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file(XML_UPLOAD_PATH . $file_name);
  var_dump($xml);
```

The as rezult is:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public 'string' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Search' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Around' (length=6)
  public 'string-array' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'fi' (length=2)
      public 'item' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'A' (length=1)
          1 => string 'Almak' (length=5)
```

First Question I dont get attribute name from string node. the secound question what is best practice to orgnize output in array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access attributes, see this example of XML parsing (courtesy of the PHP Manual) -

```
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

If you want to convert your example into an array, you can do the following -

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($string, XML_UPLOAD_PATH . $file_name, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was trying to find a way of reading the strings.xml file through PHP. When I was using simplexml_load_file all the attributes disappeared for some reason?
I worked out that the `<resources>` tag was causing the issue and that if I used simplexml_load_string just on a `<string>` tag then it would be fine.

I made this function to break each line so I could call simplexml_load_file on each `<string>` tag:

```
parse_xml('
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">My App</string>
    <string name="string_name_example">Some text</string>
    </resources>
');

function parse_xml($xml_file_contents = '') {
    // remove whitespace and return carriages in between tags
    $xml_file_contents = preg_replace("#\>((\n|\r)\s+)\<#","><",$xml_file_contents);
    // remove any left over return carriages and tabs
    $xml_file_contents = preg_replace("#\n|\r|\t#","",$xml_file_contents);
    // remove comments
    $xml_file_contents = preg_replace("#\<\!\-(.*?)\-\>#","",$xml_file_contents);
    // explode the data
    $xml_explode = explode('><',$xml_file_contents);
    $xml_data = [];
    foreach ($xml_explode as &$line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        $line = preg_replace('#^\<|\>$#','',$line);
        $line = sprintf("<%s>",$line);
        if (preg_match('#\>.*?\<#',$line,$matches)) {
            // valid
            $xml_data[] = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($line)),true);
        }
    }
    return $xml_data;
}
```

This seems to work for me and produces the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => app_name
                    [translatable] => false
                )

            [0] => My App
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => string_name_example
                )

            [0] => Some text
        )

)
```

Depending on the size of the xml data the explode function may raise the memory usage so be aware!